# When using google passport 2.0 for Oauth the "done" callback is returning global error handler error

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

When i do a get request to the google oauth i am sent to the proper google oauth screen. then when i click on a google account to log in with i hit the global error handler. it is getting caught in the passport strategy "done" callback but i cant figure out why. i will provide my code below.

server.js

```
app.get('/oauth',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['email', 'profile'] }))

app.get('/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    successRedirect: '/success',
    failureRedirect: '/failure'
  })
)
app.get('/success', (req, res) => {
  console.log('in the success')
  res.redirect('/')
})
app.get('/failure', (req, res) => {
  console.log('we in da failure')
  res.redirect('/')
})
```

passport.js

```
const passport = require("passport")
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

require('dotenv').config();
const id = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const secret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: id,
  clientSecret: secret,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:5555/callback",
  passReqToCallback: true
},
function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  console.log('in the googlestrategy')
  return done(null, profile);
}
));
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});
```

it seems to be failing at the "return done" line in the google strategy function

we've tried everything. folowing all the docs completely. hopefully someome knows whats going on here!